# Does $\mathfrak T^r(\Bbb R^m)$ count as an vector space?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Here $\mathfrak T^r (\Bbb R^m)$ denotes all the $r$-th tensors (multi-linear functions) acting upon the elements $(u_1,\cdots,u_r)$ from the product space $\displaystyle \prod^r \Bbb R^m$. And the linear structure is defined as follows:
$$(a\Phi+b\Psi)(u_1,\cdots,u_r):=a\cdot \Phi(u_1,\cdots,u_r)+b\cdot \Psi(u_1,\cdots,u_r),\quad\forall \Phi,\Psi\in\mathfrak T^r (\Bbb R^m)$$
It is easy to check that elements from  $\mathfrak T^r (\Bbb R^m)$ is closed under linear combination, and the other axioms to construct a linear space are fulfilled as well, except that I'm having trouble finding its unique zero element!

I'm aware that any such tensor under a certain cobasis $(g_1,\cdots, g_m)$ can be written into the "simple form"
$$\Phi=\Phi(g_{i_1},\cdots,g_{i_r})\cdot g^{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes g^{i_r}$$
If $\Phi$ maps any combination of $r$-$g_i$s onto $0$ then it can surely be identified as the zero element, but how to show such a zero tensor is unique? How to show there is not another way to define a zero tensor? The summation is too complicated here and I can't figure it out. Can u explain it to me ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function which is identically $0$ is multi-linear and is the unique $0$ element of this vector space.

Comment: @PVAL but is there any way to prove it rigorously?

Comment: In any group, the identity element is unique: if there were two, what do you get when you add them together?

Comment: @Vim you should answer your own question :)